# dropdown to choose specific formula from range and show result in different cell

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

Is the below possible?

Cell A1 has a dropdown whith cat,dog and mouse as the possible outcomes.

Dependant on what that cell has selected it will then pick a specific formula from a range of cells e.g B1 will have SUMIF Formula, B2 Countif Formula, B3 Vlookup etc and show the reult of that formula in Cell C1?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? How does cell A1 help in deciding what formula to choose? Do you want to choose between the 3 formulae that you have listed? Why do you want them in separate cells B1 to B3?

Comment: I want the dropdown in cell A1 to select which formula to use in cells B1 to B3 so for example if the user selects say mouse from the dropdown it will use a formula of my choosing from the range B1 to B3 and then display the result in a different cell C1 if possible. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scenario you described you'll want to use nested if statements.  The example below can be extended by replacing "No Selection" with more IFs.

```
=IF( A1="Dog", B1, IF( A1="Cat", B2, IF( A1="Mouse", B3, "No Selection")))
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect